# Changing selection around a mesh object

Tags: mesh, selection-tools, faces

I have selected some faces one one side of this object. How can I move that selection around the object to the other side, or how can I change the selection to select the same faces on other side?

[image: object with selected faces]
I want this selection on the other side of cube.

Comment: You can do that with changing a pivot point to selection or a cursor, do you want to rotate the selection around a separate object or part of the mesh?

Comment: do you mean moving the faces, or moving the selection to different faces?

Comment: I mean moving the selection to different faces.

Comment: Ctr+i will invert the selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there is no way to rotate or move the area where the selection is. The selection is selecting something whether it be objects, vertices, edges, or faces, you have to select something.

Going from your picture, and using the view in that picture; selecting the faces on the other side will be easy.

1. Change to wireframe view, in the 3D view header, or by pressing <kbd>Z</kbd>.
2. Use Border Select <kbd>B</kbd> to select the same area that is already selected. However in now wireframe both sides will get selected.
3. Change the view back to solid view, again by pressing <kbd>Z</kbd>. Now use border select, but instead of pressing with the <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd>, use the <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd>. That will unselect everything that is inside of the box.

[image: animated gif]

Answer (score 1):

There's a command in 3D View header, *Select* > *Mirror*.
It will mirror your selection by X axis (only).
So this will work only if your object is placed accordingly in World space.

Use Last Operator menu (or <kbd>F6</kbd>) to access and turn off the "*Extend*" option, it will deselect the original selection.
[image: animated gif]

Comment: That is a good way to select the other side of the mesh, but you still need to unselect the first side.

Comment: Nope, you should simply use Last Operator menu (or `F6`) to access and turn on / off `Etend` option - it will select / deselect original selection. Unfortunately, I didn't included that in answer

Comment: I did not know that, I learned something new. Thanks

Comment: Still it's possible to mirror that only along global `X` axis... I really expected this option to have something else in its options accessible.